# Buttons not displaying on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have the following portion of code:

```
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    back = new JButton("Back");
    close = new JButton("Close");
    addCruise = new JButton("Add new Cruise");
    removeCruise = new JButton("Remove Cruise");

    buttonPanel.add(close);
    buttonPanel.add(back);
    buttonPanel.add(addCruise);
    buttonPanel.add(removeCruise);

    contentPane.add(buttonPanel);
    Frame1.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Upon running the code above, all buttons are displayed on the SOUTH of the frame, except the "Close" button. I also want the buttons to span the whole width of the south portion (with no spaces between each buttons) however, I am unsure on how to implement a flow layout, and also use a border layout in order to ensure the buttons are displayed at the bottom.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Have you done Frame1.setVisible(true); ?

Comment: Can you post some more code and something which is more sequential, what is contentPane here, where is your layout settings? where are you setting the hieght,width,X,Y axis for all these?

Answer (score 1):

You have Layout in jFrame.
Add new Layout  to jPanel too.

Answer (score 1):

> *Upon running the code above, all buttons are displayed on the SOUTH of the frame, except the "Close" button.*

Hard to tell why "Close" button is missing without a proper [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides be aware that `SOUTH` constant is discouraged and we should use `PAGE_END` instead as per  standard / internationalization / language orientation trade. From [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) tutorial:

> Before JDK release 1.4, the preferred names for the various areas were
>   different, ranging from points of the compass (for example,
>   `BorderLayout.NORTH` for the top area) to wordier versions of the
>   constants we use in our examples. The constants our examples use are
>   preferred because they are standard and enable programs to adjust to
>   languages that have different orientations.

---

> *I also want the buttons to span the whole width of the south portion (with no spaces between each buttons)*

It sounds like a job for [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) (link to tutorial) with a single row instead of [FowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html).

---

> *I am unsure on how to implement a flow layout, and also use a border layout in order to ensure the buttons are displayed at the bottom.*

Your code seems to be close enough but this looks suspicious:

```
contentPane.add(buttonPanel);
Frame1.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Don't add a component to different containers. If `contentPane` is the frame's content pane then the first line is enough. If it's not then the first line is useless.